# SQL Server 2005 agent job runs a SSIS package ( Analysis Services Processing Task) fails

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

SQL Server 2005 standard edition.

I have a SSIS package which has a  Analysis Services Processing Task. I have tested the package in BIDS and it runs ok. But when I created a agent job and run it from the job it reports error:

> Code: 0xC0012024
>   Source: Analysis Services Processing Task
>   Description: The task "Analysis Services Processing Task" cannot run on this edition of Integration Services. It requires a higher level edition.

This is the result of `select @@version`

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (Intel X86)   Nov 24 2008 13:01:59   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 1)

Any ideas?

Comment: use Enterprise edition

Comment: @Jade I thought too it's probably something with the standard version of SQL Server. However we can't change that at least for now.

Comment: Have you run any SSIS packages from the SQL Agent on this machine? This smells suspiciously like the Integration Services Service is not installed

Comment: @bilinkc Yes, I have successfully run some SQL agent jobs.

Comment: All right. I have found a work around. That's to use SQL server Analysis service command in agent job then use XMLA command to process the dimensions and measures. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929186.aspx